# Secured connection between ASP.NET and Flash

Tags: asp.net, flash

I have pageA that loads sort of flash player, the url of rtmp that player listens to is hidden in other .aspx file that validates a session which generated on pageA.

Is there another way or better way to limit users from stealing the rtmp link ?

Comment: Don't you think that even with your solution users can steal the rtmp link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Flash is a client side technology you're always going to have to reveal your secrets in this way to get data into the Flash Player.

If it's a question of trusting your end user then you simply can't (in a very pesimisting world).

If you are serving the ASPX, SWF and RTMP content over HTTPS and RTMPS then your session should be *fairly* secure.

I think the thing to do would be asses your audience and possible security risks and think if what you have is "safe enough".